# ASP.NET css minification fails when filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader is used

Tags: asp.net, css, minify, system.web.optimization

I am minifying a bunch of css files and one of them contains

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader
```

as a png-transparency fix for IE6 which causes the minification proccess to fail. Is there any workaround for this problem?

Thanks!